# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table , while compiling

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Help me plzz..In first app version I wrote wrong DB_PATH in DBHelper and after install apk got exception that database not found.Then (next app version) I wrote right DB_PATH but after install get exception

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM category
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM category
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1497)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1376)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1330)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1450)
    at package.name.MainPage.update(MainPage.java:125)
    at package.name.MainPage.onCreate(MainPage.java:88)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    ... 11 more
```

If I reinstall apk with clearing caches then apk install successfull! How can I make successful installing without clearing caches and reinstall?

Main.Class

```
     ...
     public class MainPage extends MainHelper implements OnClickListener{
     ...
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
            DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

            String oldpath = "/data/data/package.name1/databases/";
            String newpath = "/data/data/package.name/databases/";
            File dbFile = new File(newpath+"db.sqlite");

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        try {
            myDbHelper.copyDataBase(oldpath);
            myDbHelper.myContext.deleteDatabase(oldpath+bd_name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        }

        try {     
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();         
        } catch (IOException ioe) {      
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");        
        }  
    .... 
    }
    }
```

DBHelper

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/package.name/databases/"; 
    private static String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite"; 
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;  
    public final Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();         

            try {
                copyDataBase(DB_PATH);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    public void copyDataBase(String bdpath) throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = bdpath + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you know the solution

---

Before doing the DB operation do the following

You shall check for the existence of db at your NEW DB PATH

if it doesn't exist

Then copy it from your OLD DB PATH {where it is expected to be}

if it is not in that also

Then create your database

Comment: read the algo i wrote that will solve the problem there is no need of db helper

Comment: @user2102260 in your inputStream of copydatabase use path of old db

Comment: File dbFile = new File(oldpath);
        
if (dbFile.exists())
try {
 myDbHelper.copyDataBase(oldpath);
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}    Run thic code before DB operation.. but get same error

Comment: @user2102260 yes and remember delete it after copy coz next time you do not replace you copied databse

Comment: File dbFile = new File(oldpath+bd_name);
        
if (dbFile.exists())
try {
 myDbHelper.copyDataBase(oldpath);
 myDbHelper.myContext.deleteDatabase(oldpath+bd_name);
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}   and now same error

Comment: you will have to modify your code read about input stream create method copyFromOldPathToNewPath then follow these things

Comment: and where is this method copyFromOldPathToNewPath described?

Comment: Update MainClass and DBHelper as its look now in my question

Comment: Sorry I have given you the Idea that how you can handle this now go and search and learn then implement with your own way do not ask me to code for you I did how much i should now your job start if you want your job done you will have to take steps

Comment: Thanks..I'm beginner in android programming..but I'm very good at other programming languages.and I always give full answers to the questions in the appropriate forums to avoid leading questions

Comment: Dear Sir, Algo is clearly solving the problem use your programming skills there is nothing behind copy files and checking their existence if all the code written above is yours then its to  easy to understand and build this also otherwise learn from oracle site , vogella's site and also developer.android.com

Comment: Update Main.Class .  Help plzzzzzz